# How to prevent css hover effects executing before you reach the element with your mouse?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bydgyo

What I want to achieve: when hovering over one quarter of the circle, give that quarter an opacity 0.6.

however, that ".home-menu__quarter" div is set to 'position:relative' in order to keep the

text over the image.

```
   <div class="home-menu__quarter home-menu__quarter--1">
     <p>text1</p>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KJg9cRl.jpg"/>
   </div>

    #home-menu .home-menu__quarter{
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      margin:0;
      float: left;
      position:relative;
    }
```

Because of the position:relative style, if I try to hover over the image, the 'opacity 0.6' kicks in before i get to the quarter (i.e the part that is hidden by the border-radius 50%.).

Any idea, no matter how hacky is welcome, because this is doing my head in. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea : [here it is](http://codepen.io/CerrahogluAli/pen/ogGvxp)

Even though you put border-radius :50%; the image on which you make the hover effect still doesn't get border-radius, it only gets clipped, so when you hover the image (the part which is clipped) , it triggers the opacity.

In my pen i removed the hover effect, and added an overlay to each `#home-menu__quarter` . this is the extra css added : (you should look at my codepen to see what i excluded)

```
.effect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.effect:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.nasty-trick-1 {
  border-top-left-radius : 150px;
}
.nasty-trick-2 {
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
}
.nasty-trick-3 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
}
.nasty-trick-4 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
}
```

So for example  this div :

```
<div class="effect nasty-trick-1"></div>
```

if it is inside the top-left quarter creates an overlay, when hovered makes the background-color black (with an alpha opacity of 0.4). Hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: Thank you so much dude. This works great. I feel stupid now for not attempting to give the inner divs or images to a border-radius too.